# Как получить номер SIM карты android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!
Не могу получить номер сим карты в телефоне программно

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
        getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}
```

И в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Не забывайте [источник](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206596/how-to-get-the-mobile-number-of-current-sim-card-in-real-device) указывать, если ответ брали со стороннего ресурса.

Comment: у меня не работает, Возвращается пустая строка